# Add Derived Attribute to pivottablejs in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pivottable.js

Quick setup notes. I'm using Jupyter notebooks via an Anaconda distribution with pivottablejs installed in the environment.

I'm trying to add a calculated metric as a derived attribute

```
pivot_ui(df, derivedAttributes={'calc_metric': calculation})
```

Documentation ([here](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters#options-object-for-pivotui)) says to set as and object of functions. I tried adding both a simple JS function (as text) and a Python function but get the following message for both: "An error occurred rendering the PivotTable UI" and type errors in the console.

Is there a way create a custom derivedAttribute for pivottablejs via Jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to create derived attributes in the Jupyter wrapper for PivotTable.js. Per the Readme of the `pivottablejs` Python module, you can only pass in JSON-serializable options from Python, and functions are not JSON-serializable... sorry!

Note: I'm the author of both libraries.